Configuring Different Versions of Shared Library for Shell and Microfrontends
I am working on a project using Module Federation with a shell application and three microfrontends (a, b, c). I need to configure the setup so that:
The shell application uses ui-library@1.0.0.
Each microfrontend (a, b) uses ui-library@1.5.0.
And c uses ui-library@1.2.0
The challenge is to configure Module Federation to handle these different versions without breaking the application or impacting performance.
Current Setup
Dependencies:
Shell Application: ui-library@1.0.0
Microfrontends: ui-library@1.5.0
Webpack Configuration:

Shell Application (webpack.config.js):
const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies;

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'shell',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      remotes: {
        a: 'a@url/aRemoteEntry.js',
        b: 'b@url/bRemoteEntry.js',
        c: 'c@url/cRemoteEntry.js',
      },
      shared: {
        'ui-library': {
          requiredVersion: '1.0.0',
          singleton: true, // Ensures only one instance of version 1.0.0
          eager: true,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};

Microfrontend A (webpack.config.js):
const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies;

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'microfrontendA',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './ComponentA': './src/ComponentA',
      },
      shared: {
        'ui-library': {
          import: 'ui-library',
          requiredVersion: '1.5.0',
          singleton: false, // Allows multiple instances of version 1.5.0
          eager: true,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};

Microfrontend B (webpack.config.js):
const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies;

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'microfrontendB',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './ComponentB': './src/ComponentB',
      },
      shared: {
        'ui-library': {
          import: 'ui-library',
          requiredVersion: '1.5.0',
          singleton: false,
          eager: true,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};

Microfrontend C (webpack.config.js):
const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies;

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'microfrontendC',
      filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
      exposes: {
        './ComponentC': './src/ComponentC',
      },
      shared: {
        'ui-library': {
          import: 'ui-library',
          requiredVersion: '1.2.0',
          singleton: false,
          eager: true,
        },
      },
    }),
  ],
};

Issues Encountered
Even after setting singleton to false for the microfrontends and singleton to true for the shell application, the setup still fails when attempting to use different versions of ui-library.
Request for Help
Can anyone provide guidance on how to configure ModuleFederationPlugin to allow the shell to use ui-library@1.0.0 while the microfrontends use different versions of ui-library? The goal is to avoid breaking the application and to maintain optimal performance. Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you for your help!

In this case we have to set singleton = false in both shell and microfrontends. because singleton = true will use highest version if multiple versions are there in the shared scope.
https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-federation-plugin/
...
singleton:
This hint only allows a single version of the shared module in the shared scope (disabled by default). Some libraries use a global internal state (e.g. react, react-dom). Thus, it is critical to have only one instance of the library running at a time.
In cases where there are multiple versions of the same dependency in the shared scope, the highest semantic version is used.
